# C++ conversion from int to bool

Tags: c++, compilation, boolean, type-conversion

I want to know if the compiled code of a *bool-to-int* conversion contains a branch (jump) operation.

For example, given `void func(bool b)` and `int i`:

Is the compiled code of calling `func(i)` equivalent to the compiled code of `func(i? 1:0)`?

Or is there a more elaborate way for the compiler to perform this without the branch operation?

**Update:**

In other words, what code does the compiler generate in order to push 1 or 0 into the stack before jumping to the address of the function?

I assume that it really comes down to the architecture of the CPU at hand, and that some specific processors (certain DSPs, for example) may support this. So my question refers to "conventional" general-purpose CPUs (assuming that this definition is acceptable).

In terms of pure software, the question can also be phrased as: is there an efficient way for converting  an integer value to 1 when it's not 0, and to 0 otherwise, **without using a conditional statement**?

Thanks

Comment: could you explain more your query??

Comment: It depends on the platform and the compiler (neither of which you specified in the question BTW). The easiest way to check is to just generate (optimised) assembly from your code, e.g. `gcc -O3 -S ...`

Comment: That depends on the compiler used, and possibly on the optimization level too.

Comment: @Axel: it also depends on what CPU you are targetting. The question is underspecified as it stands.

Comment: @Paul R: Please see my update to the question above.

Comment: @Heena Goyal: See my update to the question above (should explain the reason behind the query).

Comment: @Axel: Is there any compiler (for a specific processor I suppose) that is capable of efficiently converting an integer value to 1 when it's not 0, and to 0 otherwise, **without using a branch operation**?

Comment: `!!i` will do the trick...

Comment: @Jarod42: And that will not be compiled into a branch operation???

Comment: Most CPUs can set the zero flag (ZF) based on the value in a register (perhaps by subtracting or XORng a value with itself), and some have the ability to move the ZF back into a general purpose integral register, or to conditionally move an arbitrary value based on ZF without any actual jump/call statement (e.g. to overwrite a default of 0 with 1 if ZF is set).  So yes, it can be reasonably efficient and not involve a branch.

Comment: On x86 for example, the `setne` instruction can be used to set a register to 0 or 1 based on the ZF.

Comment: @Tony D: Thank you. I was indeed meaning to add in my question the fact that it probably depends on the CPU architecture, where there a are probably some specific ones that support this, and the question refers to "conventional general-purpose CPUs" (if such definition can be used). But I think that your two comments above are pretty much the answer that I was looking for (unlike the `!!` answer, which looks to me like a different version of the `?` operator).

Comment: @barakmanos you're welcome. Regarding `!!` - as Emilio comments below it does the same thing as casting to `bool`, or doing a test like `!= 0`: forcing the whatever-`int` to `bool` conversion.  But how that's done is no different from when it's done implicitly to call a `func(bool)`, so not relevant to your question as I understand it.

Comment: @Tony D: Thanks, I think I've already mentioned that in my comment to `Jarod42` above.

Answer (score 3):

It's not your (compiler user) job too make built-in type conversion efficient. If the compiler is not dumb, it will make that sort of things as close as the CPU representation are.

For the most of the commercial CPU, bool and int are the exact same thing, and `if(x) { ... }`
translate in bit-anding (or bit-oring, whichever is faster: they are normally immediate instructions) `x` with itself and make a conditional jump after the `}` if the zero flag is set. (not that this is just a trick to force the zero-flag computation, that is an immediate consequence of the arithmetic unit electronics)

variants are much more a matter of CPU electronics, than code. So don'care about it. `if`s are not triggered by a bool, but by the last arithmetic operation result.

Whatever arithmetic operation held by a CPU produces a result ans set some flags that represent certain result attributes: if it is zero, if it produced a carry or borrow, if it has an odd or even number of bit set to 1 etc. Resut and Flags are two registers, and can be loaded and stored from/to memory.

Comment: `if(x) { ... }` is not the scenario the question is about.  The question asks very specifically how an integer might be tested and a register or the stack prepared with a 0 or 1 value in preparation for a function call expecting a `bool` argument.  That's more complicated than checking the integer and using it to branch, and indeed the question focuses on not how efficient such a branch is, but whether one would be needed to prepare the register/stack for the call....

Comment: The point is that there is no such a need, since every operation you'll do boils down to nothing in the most of the cases: `a = bool(x)` or `a = !!x` or `a = (x!=0)` if x is a built-in type are the same and do nothing else than making `a = is_zero(x&x)`.

Comment: Ok - you've edited your comment above with mention of is_zero(x&x).  Anyway, regarding "for the most of the commercial CPU, bool and int are exactly the same thing" - C++ compilers may use single byte `bool` variables, and make it an invariant that they're set 0 or 1 and not some other non-0 value that needs interpretation on read.  [Demonstated on ideone here](http://ideone.com/4k0Qus) and confirmed for VC++ on my PC.

Comment: If you have a better answer just write it! to me that's just useless nitpicking.

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia: Thank you for your detailed answer. My question in specific is, how does the compiler generate a code which pushes 1 or 0 into the stack before jumping to the address of the function? Thanks again :) ... perhaps I should add it in the question...

Comment: @barakmanos: it calls an arithmetic/logic operation that does not change the result, and pushes the value of the resulting zero flag into the stack. It looks "strange" but they are both immediate instructions: whatever trivial arithmetic operation sets a result and sets some flags (the result and the flags are two CPU internal register). If you want to know if a value is zero just "do nothing" to it and the zero flag will set accordingly. The zero flag is just the result of an electronic NOR between between the result bits. It's not an instruction, it's just part of what the CPU is.

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia: So the compiler simply replaces the int-to-bool conversion with a logical OR with 0 (or a logical AND with 1)?

Comment: No, it replaces the value with the zero flag value (eventually inverted) as it was generated during the operation that produced the value. If that was not the last executed arithmetic operation, a dummy "no change" operation is made. The key point is the zero flag of the flag register in the CPU.