# Purpose of bitwise OR of an integer with its negative

Tags: c, integer, bitwise-or

I was curious about the implementation and representation of `NaN` in both IEEE single- and double-precision floating points, and I found [this implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/isnan.c) of an "is NaN" function. Namely:

```
int isnan(double x)
{
    int32_t hx,lx;

    // Move lower 32 bits of double to lx, higher 32 to hx.
    EXTRACT_WORDS(hx,lx,x);

    // Remove sign bit, since -NaN and NaN are both NaN.
    hx &= 0x7fffffff;

    // Equivalent to hx |= (lx != 0).
    hx |= (u_int32_t)(lx|(-lx))>>31;

    // Difference is negative iff (hx & 0x7ff00000) == 0x7ff00000 and (hx & 0x000fffff) != 0.
    hx = 0x7ff00000 - hx;
    return (int)((u_int32_t)(hx))>>31;
}
```

I didn't understand the purpose of `(lx|(-lx)) >> 31`, and after failing to reason it out in my head, I tested it on all integers, and found it results in 0 for `lx = 0` and 1 otherwise.

The only reasons I could come up with are that perhaps using `(lx != 0)` instead was not possible due to some C standard not defining what integer value is assigned to true operations (e.g. not guaranteed to be 1 for true) or that perhaps `!=` is slower than the negative-or-and-bit-shift. Otherwise, I'm stumped.

For reference, the code I used to try all integers, in case of errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void) {
        int32_t i = 0;
        do {
                if (((uint32_t)(i | (-i)) >> 31) == 0)
                        printf("%d\n", i); // prints only 0
        } while (i++ != 0xFFFFFFFF); // overflows to -max_int and then climb to -1
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print out the bit patterns for `lx` and `-lx` respectively, and see what you find out from that.

Comment: It removes a conditional jump.

Comment: Joachim, now that I see the result, I can see why it's only 1 for 0, because if it's non-zero, then the most significant bit (sign bit) for either `lx` or `-lx` will be 1 (and thus when you bit-shift 31 right, it'll be 1). My question is why not use `(lx != 0)` instead of the comparison.

Comment: Raymond, would `hx |= (u_int32_t)(lx != 0)` not work in this case (does not have a conditional jump as far as I can see)? Is a true expression not guaranteed to be converted to an integer value of 1 by some C standard?

Comment: Minor correction to my comment to Joachim: it's only 0 for 0, not only 1 for 0.

Comment: Aside from the specific expression you're asking about, I don't see how this code does anything like determine if a `double` is a `NaN` value. I don't see how it returns anything but 0.  It appears to be very old code that has since been replaced - I suspect it's simply several lines of buggy code.

Comment: Michael, from my understanding, a floating point is `NaN` if the exponent bits are all 1's and the significand/mantissa bits are all 0's. I hit a snag with trying to unravel the mystery of that expression, so I didn't look at the rest of the function too deeply, but my intuition says it should work. Since the lower 32 bits of a double are all part of the significand, I believe the idea is to put a 1 at the end of the higher bit int32 if there are any non-zero bits in the lower bits (thus, the comparison with 0) and then check for any 1s in the significand bits from the upper half.

Comment: It's a nasty bit of code and could be made loads neater, but I'm nonetheless intrigued by what appears to be unwieldy optimization soup.

Comment: what is `EXTRACT_WORDS` ?

Comment: @Jengerer: thank you - I'm not sure what I was doing wrong in my previous attempts to work through what the code was doing, but you've hit it on the head (except that NaN has a non-zero mantissa; if the manitssa is all zeros then that indicates infinity). This once again proves that I should always avoid problems dealing with floating point.

Comment: @Michael: thanks for the correction. What lead to me looking up this code initially was learning that any floating point equality/inequality with one of operands being NaN results in false. Thus, `NaN == NaN` is false, and perhaps more scary, `NaN > x` does not give the same result for `!(NaN <= x)`.

Comment: @Jengerer: yup - floating point is a minefield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(u_int32_t)(lx|(-lx))>>31` is equivalent to `lx==0? 0:1`.

However, with `lx==0? 0:1`, you are imposing a branch operation into the object code.

This might yield reduced performance in comparison with a couple of bit-wise operations.

It really depends on the underlying HW architecture as well as the designated compiler at hand.

But it will for sure lead to **inconsistent performance**, depending on branch-prediction heuristics.

The running time of `(u_int32_t)(lx|(-lx))>>31` is guaranteed to be identical on every execution.

Comment: `abs(lx)` is the absolute value of `lx` , it doesn't bear any resemblance to `lx|-lx`

Comment: @barakmanos: what does `3 | (-3)` give on your machine?  On mine it gives `-1`.

Comment: `-abs(lx)` is the absolute value of `lx` negated. For example if `lx` is 3, then `-abs(lx)` is `-3`, and `lx|-lx` is `-1`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yep, miscalculated that in my head... answer revised... thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Onto another point now, surely one would expect one's compiler to select the fastest implementation (if optimizing for speed). Perhaps this code was written for a bad compiler.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I doubt that very much. To be fair, a branch operation will pretty much **always** yield reduced performance in comparison with a couple of bit-wise operations. I used "might" because I did not want to make a conclusive statement, as there might be some HW architecture out there, with a unique instruction-set (or even just a single instruction) specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know off the top of your head why simply converting `lx != 0` to an integer would not suffice? Does that branch internally, or is there no guarantee that the results would be 1 and 0 for true and false, respectively?

Comment: @Jengerer: No, I believe that the result is guaranteed to be 1 or 0. But to the best of my knowledge, that's what every compiler designated for a general purpose processor does. Specifically designated processors (like DSPs for example) may provide an that supports this conversion without branching. As I explained in the answer simply converting `lx != 0` to an integer is sufficient, but yields a branch operation (with its subsequent repercussions, as explained in the answer) into the compiled code.

Comment: @Jengerer: Regardless of the above, you might be happy to know that your question has in fact provided an answer to a question that I had published here myself a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22500119/1382251.

Comment: @barakmanos: Thanks for the response. I did indeed see that in converting `int x = (a != 0)`, there was an instruction in x86 for setting a byte to 0/1 if an operand was zero/non-zero, but I can believe that there are platforms that would use a branch instead.

Comment: @Jengerer: You're welcome. Did you mean "I believe that there are platforms that use something other than branch"? As I said, there might be specifically designated HW architectures, like DSP for example, that have a dedicated op-code for that purpose.

Comment: @barakmanos: I took at look at x86 assembly implementation of something like `return (x != 0)`, and it does use the instruction `setne register` to do it without a branch. I meant I suppose that, as you suggested, the `lx | (-lx)` is a solution that's guaranteed not to use a branch even for platforms that don't have an instruction like `setne`.

Comment: @Jengerer: `setne` sounds to me like an abbreviation of *set (if) not equal*, which in turn, sounds to me like a branch operation.

Comment: @barakmanos: From some documentation I read, it sets the destination byte to 1 if the `ZF` flag set from the previous comparison is 0, and 0 otherwise, so I imagine it could be implemented by just assigning `0b0000000<negation ZF>` to the destination register. I suppose it's not immediately apparent that this is the implementation that is used, however.

Comment: @Jengerer: Note the "if" that you quoted from the documentation. This is pretty straightforward branching, nothing too complicated here. The `sne` indeed performs an immediate operation according to the value of the `ZF` flag, but in order for that flag to attain a value of 0 or 1 according to the value of the input argument (`lx` in our example), the processor has to make a "branching decision" (something like, if `lx == 0` then `ZF = 1`, otherwise `ZF = 0`).

Comment: @barakmanos: Good point, I didn't think that the actual comparison might have to do some branching to set the `ZF` flag.

Comment: @Jengerer: The branching will not necessarily yield reduced performance comparing to  that "OR trick" (although I believe that it will do, at least on most architectures). But since the value of the input argument is unknown, it will yield **inconsistent** performance, depending on that value, and subjected to the branch-prediction heuristics of the underlying HW architecture.